# Greengrass-cli: Command not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, aws-iot-greengrass

I am working on AWS Greengrass with raspberry pi4. I have successfully installed all the necessary software for this and also have done some deployments but after the one or two deployments, I found error: bash: greengrass-cli : command not found. Can anyone tell me about the issue behind it.
If I install all necessary software so this error should not be happen.

Comment: Per the [installation instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v2/developerguide/install-gg-cli.html), add your /greengrass/v2/bin folder to your PATH variable.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It seems that you have accidentally removed the "aws.greengrass.Cli" component from your deployment. Without this component there is no greengrass-cli